# Get Sybase ASE hardware information

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I've search around and found some useful procedures, such as:

```
sp_helpdevice
sp_helpserver
sp_configure
```

But no one can help me. I need to get the information about CPU, RAM, OS etc. Is there a tool or procedure that can help me?

Comment: Since MSSQL is derived from Sybase I hope [this link](http://sqldbpool.com/2011/10/19/script-to-get-the-cpu-and-memory-information/) should help

Comment: @nimesh I think the regread commands are SQL Server specific, but `xp_cmdshell` gives access to the shell, and could be used to pull information from the OS.

Comment: @MichaelGardner I was referring to `sys.dm_os_sys_info` (giving the details about CPU/RAM) procedure mentioned in the post which should work on Sybase too.

Comment: @Nimesh that was added to SQL Server 2005, so it too is not available in ASE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xp_cmdshell` to access an OS shell.  You'll need to have the XP Server installed and running for the procedure to be enabled.

```
xp_cmdshell command[, no_output] [return_status | no_wait]
```

The commands to get the information will depend on whether you are running on Windows or *nix, but here are a couple of examples from the documentation.

> Example 1 – (On Windows) Silently copies the file named log on the C
> drive to a file named log.0102 on the A drive: xp_cmdshell 'copy
> C:\log A:\log.0102', no_output
>
> Example 2 – (On UNIX) Executes the
> operating system’s ls command and returns the list directory contents
> as a row of data: xp_cmdshell 'ls'

Full documentation can be found in the [Reference Manual: Procedures](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36273.1600/doc/html/san1393052115747.html)

Comment: Looks great, but I don't have permission on executing this procedure((

Comment: @Daria if you can't get access then you will have to settle for doing it via OS shell outside of the database.  Without access to xp_cmdshell you will not be able to find much more than the platform for the server.